# Set 2 way binding property to Host Element Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there a way to dynamically add a 2 way binding [(somemodel)] property to a Host element in Angular 4 ?

```
<my-comp></mycomp>
```

We would like to replace the above markup to look like

```
<my-comp [(somemodel)]="modelvalue" ></mycomp>
```

dynamically at run time. We are aware the @HostBinding does not support this, as the most common examples we have seen are adding class or attributes to host.
Is there any way to replace the host element like this using Angular 4 ?
We are open to dynamically loading templates/components if someone can point us to the right direction.

In Angular 1, we used to replace the host element markup with our text and do a $compile(scope). Is there a similar approach in Angular 4 using dynamic loading ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is @Input in Angular 4.  It allows you to define a variable on your component and receive it's value from the HTML.  Here are the [Angular Docs on Input/Output](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties--input-and-output-)

And a quick example

In your component, import 'Input' from Angular Core

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Then, define your input variable.  Here, I'm for a loading variable that is a boolean.

```
@Input() loading:boolean = false;
```

Then, in your HTML define the binding.

```
<loader [loading]="loading"></loader>
```

Remember that the 'loading' inside of the brackets will match the name of your input variable.

Comment: Only issue i need to set this attribute on the Host Element. And i don't think I can use @HostBinding to set a two way binding property [(someattr)] on host element.

Comment: @user636525 what do you mean by host element?

Comment: James: I have edited the question, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Unfortunately, I'm still not exactly sure what you're looking for and not sure what host element means.  This might just be my misunderstanding :)